# Form isn't serializing when I am using jquery load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am loading a div with content from another page for an example:

```
$("#content").load("<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>employment/new_employment" + " #inner_main_content");
```

I have stored my form serialize data in the footer which is included on the main page,

**Ajax**

```
   <!-- process add employment form without refreshing, then load the div with the new information !-->
    $('#add_employment_form').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(responseText) {
                $('#add_employment').text("+ <?php echo System::translate("Add employment "); ?>");
                $(".add_qualification_json").slideUp("slow");
                $("#content").load("<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>employment/employment" + " #inner_main_content");
            }
        });
        return false; // important: prevent the form from submitting
    });
    <!-- end process add employment form without refreshing, then load the div with the new information !-->
```

This is my form in another page which is being loaded in to the page with the header and footer:

**Form**

```
<form role="form" action="<?php echo Config::get('URL');?>employment/add_employment" method="POST" id="add_employment_form">
```

But this is not processing and the form keeps submitting like normal. Can we not serialize forms when they're being loaded dynamically from another page?

console errors:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) select2.min.js:1 Uncaught Error: jquery.select2 missing
>   ./select2/core wysihtml5.min.js:20 'Range.detach' is now a no-op, as
>   per DOM (http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-range-detach).
>   http://localhost/github/Logo.png
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) VM143:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
>   radLogo.png:1 GET
>   http://localhost/github/Logo.png
>   404 (Not Found)

Comment: Um @rybo111 `return false` cancels it...

Comment: My bet is the fact you are trying to hook up the event listener before the form is added to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are loading the form dynamically so probably the event handler is not binding to the form since it does not exist.

Use event delegation

```
$('#add_employment_form').submit(function() {
```

to

```
$("#content").on("submit", "#add_employment_form", function() {
```

Comment: That made it work, I just changed content to the other div class I was using due to me loading one page in content, then the add form content to another div inside that div, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Edit, I did two functions for both separate pages, and both work a charm, thank you Epascarello

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell jQuery to prevent the event's normal processing using `.preventDefault()`.

Change -

```
$('#add_employment_form').submit(function() {
```

to

```
$('#add_employment_form').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
```